# C++ bad_alloc exception on future.get

Tags: c++, c++11, debugging, memory, gdb

My C++ program is exiting with a bad_alloc exception. I'm trying to find the cause, but don't quite know how to debug these kind of exceptions.

So far, I compiled the program in debug mode, run it with gdb and set a breakpoint before throwing the exception (`b 'std::bad_alloc::bad_alloc()'`).

After the exception was thrown, I inspected the stack (`bt`), which showed the following:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff752f1f7 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff75308e8 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff7f0a7fd in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler () at ../../../../libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/vterminate.cc:95
#3  0x00007ffff7f08876 in __cxxabiv1::__terminate (handler=<optimized out>) at ../../../../libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_terminate.cc:47
#4  0x00007ffff7f088c1 in std::terminate () at ../../../../libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_terminate.cc:57
#5  0x00007ffff7f0886a in std::rethrow_exception (ep=...) at ../../../../libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_ptr.cc:259
#6  0x0000000000419001 in std::__basic_future<void>::_M_get_result (this=0x55b9a0)
    at /soft/EB_repo/devel/programs/foss/2016b/GCCcore/5.4.0/include/c++/5.4.0/future:683
#7  0x0000000000416da6 in std::future<void>::get (this=0x55b9a0) at /soft/EB_repo/devel/programs/foss/2016b/GCCcore/5.4.0/include/c++/5.4.0/future:846
#8  0x00000000004d152f in cluster_reads (reads=..., kmer_size=14, t_s=0.10000000000000001, t_v=500, bv_threshold=0.40000000000000002, 
    min_bv_threshold=0.20000000000000001, bv_falloff=0.050000000000000003, min_reads_cluster=0, n_threads=8) at cluster.cpp:81
#9  0x000000000040910b in main (argc=8, argv=0x7fffffffc028) at main.cpp:106
```

As you can see in #7, the exception is being thrown when getting the std::future? Here is the piece of code from cluster_reads (#8) that is crashing (I marked line 81 with an arrow).

```
    std::vector<std::vector<kmer_t>> kmers(reads.size());
    std::vector<std::vector<kmer_t>> rev_kmers(reads.size());

    std::vector<kmer_bv_t> bv_kmers(reads.size());
    std::vector<kmer_bv_t> rev_bv_kmers(reads.size());

    std::vector<std::future<void>> tasks;
    for (int t = 0; t < n_threads; ++t) {
        tasks.emplace_back(std::async(std::launch::async, [t, &reads, n_threads, kmer_size, &kmers, &rev_kmers, &bv_kmers, &rev_bv_kmers] {
            for (int i = t; i < reads.size(); i+=n_threads) {
                read_kmers_t k1 = extract_kmers_from_read(reads[i].seq, kmer_size);

                kmers[i] = k1.list_forward;
                rev_kmers[i] = k1.list_reverse;
                bv_kmers[i] = k1.bv_forward;
                rev_bv_kmers[i] = k1.bv_reverse;
            }
        }));
    }

    for (auto &&task : tasks) {
        task.get(); <------------------- line 81
    }
```

How can I debug further this issue? I'm pretty new to gdb. Any idea on what might be causing the bad_alloc exception?

Comment: Since your future returns `void` there shouldn't be anything that needs allocating which is puzzling. What happens if you use `wait` instead of `get`?

Comment: @NathanOliver using wait instead of get seems to have solved the problem. It's still weird tho. Should I always use wait instead of get if my future returns void?

Comment: AFAIK `get` effectively calls `wait` so you shouldn't need to.  One thing you can do is check if `valid` is true before calling `get`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems an `std::bad_alloc` is thrown in one of the threads, and it is later rethrown by `task.get()` (which you mistakenly think is the source of the exception). Here is a quote from [`future::get()` cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/get)

> **Exceptions**
>   If an exception was stored in the shared state referenced by the future (e.g. via a call to `std::promise::set_exception())` then that exception will be thrown.

This can happen due to allocating of `std::vector<kmer_t>` at:

```
read_kmers_t k1 = extract_kmers_from_read(reads[i].seq, kmer_size);
```

and later in:

```
kmers[i] = k1.list_forward;
```

From the names of the variables, I assume that you are reading genome databases, which could be big and exhaust your memory if you are not being careful.

To catch the exact moment when the exception is thrown you should tell gdb:

```
 (gdb) catch throw
```

Which will stop execution where the original exception is thrown.

Comment: Ahh, the catch throw did the trick. I was allocating a vector with a negative size in another file due to a small DNA read (`std::vector<kmer_t> read_kmers = std::vector<kmer_t>(read.length()-kmer_size);`). What were the consequences of using wait instead of get? Because using wait the exception was not thrown..

Comment: @Ivan as the name implies, wait just waits for the task to complete. It does not get any return value (there is none in this case) neither does it rethrow exceptions. That's all. All `wait` does is to wait for the thread to complete, nothing more. It does not free resources, like thread handle, or exception objects

Comment: Michael Veksler what happens with that vector that is incorrectly initialized? It is being used later. Is it empty?

Comment: @Ivan, it can't be initialized incorrectly. If the constructor throws an exception, then the object does not exist and you can't access it. If it is still accessed by some kind of trickery, then it would be an undefined behavior. If the vector is initialized correctly, but later resized to an invalid size https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize "If an exception is thrown, this function has no effect" . [there is a complication when move constructor is not noexcept and it may be that "the guarantee is waived and the effects are unspecified", but most likely not in your case]